# Count occurence of 1 value depending on value of another column

Tags: sql

Im currently studying sql and I have the issue below:

Consider the table below:

```
______________________________
Food     |  Ingredients
______________________________
Soup     |   Pepper
Soup     |   Salt
Soup     |   Salt
Soup     |   Meat
Main     |   Salt
Main     |   Salt
Main     |   Meat
```

What I want to do is to count the number of ingredients per unique value of food so it produces this table.

```
________________________________________
Food     |  Ingredients   | Count 
________________________________________
Soup     |   Pepper       |   1
Soup     |   Salt         |   2
Soup     |   Salt         |   2
Soup     |   Meat         |   1
Main     |   Salt         |   3
Main     |   Salt         |   3
Main     |   Salt         |   3
Main     |   Meat         |   2
Main     |   Meat         |   2
```

How would one create a query for this? Thanks!

Comment: which sql version? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your expected output shows Soup with Salt twice, each with a count of 2. Do you not want to eliminate duplicates from your output?

Comment: Hint: `group by` and `count` are your friends here.

Answer (score 2):

This would work in SQL Server (if that's what you're using)

```
SELECT Food, Ingredients, COUNT(Ingredients) AS IngredientCount
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Food, Ingredients
```

Comment: Yes im using SQL Server and this is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by Food, Ingredients) as cnt
from t;
```

Of course, your desired results don't match the input data, so this is based on your explanation of what you want.